# What distribution is being used for this moment generating function?

Tags: calculus, probability

I'm being asked to find the probability $P(Z < 1)$ from the given moment generating function:

$$\frac{1}{1-t/2}\left(\frac{1+2e^t}{3}\right)^4$$

Clearly it's a special distribution, but I can't tell which one.
It's a practice exercise which hinted at using a non-existent theorem in the book, so I have turned here.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Notice that MGF of exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ is $$\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{t}{\lambda}}$$
and 
$$\left(\frac{1+2e^t}{3} \right)^4$$ is an MGF of a  binomial distribution.

Let the exponential distribution be $X$ and the binomial distribution be $Y$.

Our distribution is $Z=X+Y$. To have $Z<1$ notice that $Y=0$.

Comment: So, I'm assuming I would just use the sum-product property of moment generating functions to find out the original pdf function?

Comment: the distribution is a sum of two independent distribution, one is an exponential distribution, one is a binomial distribution.

Comment: added a bit more info. You do no thave to find the whole pdf to solve the problem.